# TSQL OPENJSON when path has funky charactors

Tags: json, t-sql, open-json

My JSON financial time series data is from alphavantage

I suspect without the spaces and periods (.) in the path labels I'd be fine. I managed to get the TSQL to run without the parser fussing but not path node data. Are the special characters the cause?

```
 DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @JSON = 
'{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "XLK",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-06-30",
        "4. Output Size": "Full size",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-06-30": {
            "1. open": "102.6600",
            "2. high": "104.9100",
            "3. low": "102.5200",
            "4. close": "104.4900",
            "5. volume": "8061852"
        },
        "2020-06-29": {
            "1. open": "101.5300",
            "2. high": "102.6600",
            "3. low": "100.3100",
            "4. close": "102.6500",
            "5. volume": "9271548"
        },
        "2020-06-26": {
            "1. open": "103.3800",
            "2. high": "103.5300",
            "3. low": "101.2300",
            "4. close": "101.5400",
            "5. volume": "22135104"
        },
        "2020-06-25": {
            "1. open": "102.4200",
            "2. high": "103.6900",
            "3. low": "101.3100",
            "4. close": "103.5800",
            "5. volume": "10265454"
        },
        "2020-06-24": {
            "1. open": "104.2000",
            "2. high": "104.7800",
            "3. low": "101.7100",
            "4. close": "102.2700",
            "5. volume": "12710857"
        },
        "2020-06-23": {
            "1. open": "104.8100",
            "2. high": "105.8300",
            "3. low": "104.4800",
            "4. close": "104.6300",
            "5. volume": "9508806"
        },
        "2020-06-22": {
            "1. open": "102.0900",
            "2. high": "103.9700",
            "3. low": "101.9300",
            "4. close": "103.8800",
            "5. volume": "7365608"
        },
        "2020-06-19": {
            "1. open": "104.1900",
            "2. high": "104.3100",
            "3. low": "101.7500",
            "4. close": "102.2400",
            "5. volume": "15638477"
        },
        "2020-06-18": {
            "1. open": "102.3000",
            "2. high": "103.0600",
            "3. low": "102.0800",
            "4. close": "102.9500",
            "5. volume": "6853710"
        },
        "2020-06-17": {
            "1. open": "103.0900",
            "2. high": "103.4600",
            "3. low": "102.3200",
            "4. close": "102.4900",
            "5. volume": "8655904"
        },
        "2020-06-16": {
            "1. open": "102.7700",
            "2. high": "103.3900",
            "3. low": "100.9200",
            "4. close": "102.5100",
            "5. volume": "13967902"
        },
        "2020-06-15": {
            "1. open": "97.6000",
            "2. high": "100.8200",
            "3. low": "97.2800",
            "4. close": "100.3700",
            "5. volume": "14961914"
        },
        "2020-06-12": {
            "1. open": "100.7700",
            "2. high": "101.2700",
            "3. low": "97.6800",
            "4. close": "99.4100",
            "5. volume": "21642002"
        },
        "2020-06-11": {
            "1. open": "102.3000",
            "2. high": "102.4500",
            "3. low": "98.1100",
            "4. close": "98.1400",
            "5. volume": "19867498"
        },
        "2020-06-10": {
            "1. open": "103.1400",
            "2. high": "104.8900",
            "3. low": "102.9500",
            "4. close": "104.1100",
            "5. volume": "12177473"
        },
        "2020-06-09": {
            "1. open": "101.4100",
            "2. high": "102.9000",
            "3. low": "101.3200",
            "4. close": "102.4000",
            "5. volume": "7352624"
        },
        "2020-06-08": {
            "1. open": "101.2300",
            "2. high": "101.9600",
            "3. low": "100.3000",
            "4. close": "101.9200",
            "5. volume": "8064775"
        },
        "2020-06-05": {
            "1. open": "99.5100",
            "2. high": "101.7000",
            "3. low": "99.3400",
            "4. close": "101.4100",
            "5. volume": "10374918"
        }
    }
}
'



    SELECT 
           *
    FROM OPENJSON(@JSON,'$."Time Series (Daily)"') 
    WITH(   

            series_open VARCHAR(18) '$."1. open"',
            searies_high VARCHAR(128) '$."2. high"',
            series_close VARCHAR(128) '$."4. close"',
            searies_volumn VARCHAR(28) '$."5. volume"'

          )
```

Nice to have:
Meta Data repeated for the entire set
The Date repeated for each of the 5 subnodes in the path.

Thanks experts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will give you enough to solve this on your own hopefully:

Your JSON (reduced to just some nodes):

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "XLK",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-06-30",
        "4. Output Size": "Full size",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-06-30": {
            "1. open": "102.6600",
            "2. high": "104.9100",
            "3. low": "102.5200",
            "4. close": "104.4900",
            "5. volume": "8061852"
        },
        "2020-06-29": {
            "1. open": "101.5300",
            "2. high": "102.6600",
            "3. low": "100.3100",
            "4. close": "102.6500",
            "5. volume": "9271548"
        },
        "2020-06-26": {
            "1. open": "103.3800",
            "2. high": "103.5300",
            "3. low": "101.2300",
            "4. close": "101.5400",
            "5. volume": "22135104"
        }
    }
}'
```

--the query

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(A.[Meta Data],'$."1. Information"') AS Meta_Information
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[Meta Data],'$."2. Symbol"') AS Meta_Symbol
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[Meta Data],'$."3. Last Refreshed"') AS Meta_LastRefreshed
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[Meta Data],'$."4. Output Size"') AS Meta_OutputSize
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[Meta Data],'$."5. Time Zone"') AS Meta_TimeZone
      ,B.[key] AS Data_Date
      ,C.*
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) WITH([Meta Data]           NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
                         ,[Time Series (Daily)] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON ) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.[Time Series (Daily)]) B
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(B.[value]) WITH([1. open] DECIMAL(10,4)
                                    ,[2. high] DECIMAL(10,4)
                                    --and so on
                                    ) C;
```

The idea in short:

- We use `OPENJSON()` together with a `WITH`-clause to get the first level (`Meta` and `Time Series`).
- We use `AS JSON` to tell the engine, that the result is still JSON and not a simple text.
- Now we can use `JSON_VALUE()` to read the MetaData directly (this would work directly against `@JSON` too).
- We can use `OPENJSON()` again to dive deeper.
- It is a bad habit to use a descriptive part as content. The keys, which are the date-values acutally should better be all of the same name and carry the date within the object... Nevertheless we can use `OPENJSON` **without** the `WITH`-clause to retrieve the `key` (= the date) and the `value` (= the object) column.
- Another `OPENJSON()` gets the `value` as input and will return the internal values.

Comment: Wonderful. This is a huge help Shnugo